# Error in finding string of words that are present in one column is also present in another or not?

Tags: r

I am trying to find whether a string that is present in column one of a dataframe is also present in another column of the same dataframe or not?

```
col1 <- c("ISAACS INN",
  "THIZAS PLACE",
  "ZINIKO TAVERN",
  "HANJIS RESTAURANT",
  "ULTIMATE")

col2 <- c("ISAACS IS INN",
          "HER THIZAS ARE PLACE",
          "HIS ZINIKO NAME TAVERN SO",
          "HANJIS SWEET HEIR RESTAURANT",
          "THIS IS ULTIMATE NAME")

df <- data.frame(col1, col2, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

And I followed this to try to find an answer:

```
testdf <- as.data.frame(transform(df, 
                                  word_exists = mapply(grepl, pattern=df$col1, 
                                                       x=df$col2) & nzchar(df$col1)))
```

Which failed to return me exactly what I was looking for.

what am I doing wrong in above code?

Is there an alternative to it?

The result that I got:

[image]

Comment: Could you add your expected output?

Comment: @drmariod - I just added the result

Comment: Is that the incorrect output that you're currently getting? It's probably more useful to show the correct output that you would want.

Comment: Where is your expected output? Do you mean `mapply(grepl, gsub('\\s+', '|', df$col1), df$col2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
lapply(df$col1, function(x) grepl(paste(strsplit(x,' ')[[1]], collapse='.*'), df$col2))
```

I just changed each line in `df$col1` to a regex which can have anything (`.*`) in between the two words.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am just wondering the results i got using it. it is confusing me, i am sorry. can i get something like in dataframe. Also I wanted to clarify, if it works in case if there are more than two words in Col1 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to look for the individual parts, here's a hackish `tidyverse` alternative:

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = col1) %>%
  separate_rows(col1, sep =" ") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate( flg = if_else(grepl(col1,col2), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(word_exists = prod(flg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(col1 = id, col2, word_exists) %>%
  unique()
```

It splits the `pattern` into separate rows, and checks for each of the components. Then gives a positive result where all parts of the `pattern` gave a positive result.

output:

```
               col1                         col2 word_exists
              <chr>                        <chr>       <dbl>
1        ISAACS INN                ISAACS IS INN           1
2      THIZAS PLACE         HER THIZAS ARE PLACE           1
3     ZINIKO TAVERN    HIS ZINIKO NAME TAVERN SO           1
4 HANJIS RESTAURANT HANJIS SWEET HEIR RESTAURANT           1
5          ULTIMATE        THIS IS ULTIMATE NAME           1
```

Comment: I am just wondering the results i got using it. it is confusing me, i am sorry. can i get something like in dataframe. Also I wanted to clarify, if it works in case if there are more than two words in Col1 ?

Comment: @ManojKumar It is a dataframe, and it works irrespective of the number of words, but you can always create a sample with more than two words in `col1` and test it yourself. Also, it's always advisable to post a new question with some sample data rather than using comments for follow-ups.